# Invoke multiple services in WCF at the same time to different contract

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed a WCF service which calls two clients to send files to each client.
I have done this by calling a single client and transferring the file is working fine. When I implement with more than one client it is getting a concurrency issue. I have looked at

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

But it's not working. When I debug, both service are executing in parallel and having problems with file resources.

Here is my client endpoint:

```xml
<client>
    <endpoint address="xedt027/LeapClient/FileTransfer.svc"; binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" contract="ServiceReference1.IFileTransfer" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" />
    <endpoint address="localhost:50152/FileTransfer.svc"; binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer1" contract="ServiceReference2.IFileTransfer" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer1" />
</client>
```

Comment: can you show us some code? Guess in the dark: While you read the file on the 1st Server it locks it for your second instance

Comment: Here my client endpoint   <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xedt027/LeapClient/FileTransfer.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IFileTransfer" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:50152/FileTransfer.svc" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer1" 
        contract="ServiceReference2.IFileTransfer" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer1" />
    </client>

Comment: i am invoking two service sametime..each call one client to send file.