# wcf invoke single service from server that call multiple clients to transfer file

Tags: wcf

i have been working in wcf that invoke single service that call methods  from different client to send file from server to multiple clients.i have implemented like pick the file from servicer using service and call filetransffer method which is implemented in client code where client's local file path is mentioned.

Now all working file when i invoke single service and call method from single client and save file over there in client.but when i try to connect with onemore client it getting issue.

My question is 
Do i need to create another same service to call another client? if no need Is there any method to call multiple client for single method.
Here is my current one to one service and client configuration.

Comment: <client>
      <endpoint address="http://xedt027/LeapClient/FileTransfer.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IFileTransfer" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" />
    </client>

Comment: <services>
      <service name="LeapServer.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="LeapServer.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8737/Design_Time_Addresses/LeapServer/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968231/invoke-multiple-service-in-wcf-at-same-time-to-different-contract)